# 3000 px tall movie clip registers as 20 million px to AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

This is for a scroller, I've been trying to figure out why it's pushing a particular movie clip off stage for a particular clip, when the others are working fine. Tracing the numbers, the clip is off at y -76000 and Flash thinks the height is somewhere in the neighborhood of 20 million, 20133131.85 to be exact.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Obvious question but it's not being scaled by code elsewhere, is it?

Answer (score 0):

can you trace the bounds on enterframe? this sounds much like the clip is not ready yet for some reason. if this is the case, the numbers should become normal after some time.

Answer (score -1):

manually assign the proper height to the clip in actionscript. that way flash knows what's up.